# jQuery search for paragraphs containing multiple words

Tags: javascript, jquery, search

I have an unordered list called test

```
<ul id='test'></ul>
```

it is dynamically populated with data via ajax. Each item 'li' is a div containing 'p' paragraphs. Each paragraph contains some information.

Ex:

```
<li> <div> <p> test </p> </div> </li>
<li> <div> <p> hi how is it going?</p> </div> </li>
<li> <div> <p> not a test</p> </div> </li> 
<li> <div> <p> whoa</p> </div> </li>
```

I also have a search box which i can get a search term from, I use:

```
var searchTerm = $("#search").val().trim().split(' '); // an array of words searched for
```

What I am trying to do is find a way to select all 'li' elements which contain all or some of the search words, but I'm not sure how to approach it best.

Currently, I am doing this:

```
var results = $('p:contains("'+ searchTerm[0] +'")');
```

to get an exact match on the first term, but I want to search for multiple terms, not just one.

I would want to search for 'test hi' and get back three nodes cause it searches for 'test' and 'hi'.
I also thought of:

```
var results2 = $('p').filter(function( index ) {
    return ( this +':contains("'+ searchTerm +'")' );
});
```

Anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Hmm... careful with that [tag:regex] tag... don't want to fall afoul of the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)!

Comment: sorry, I thought that in some way regex could be used here. I'll remove it.

Comment: Not a problem, I've just noticed that regex-tagged questions tend to attract a lot of negative attention when regex solutions are unwarranted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do some black magic with the selector, like this:

```
var results = $('p:contains("' + searchTerm.join('"), p:contains("') + '")');
```

This looks hard, but I'll explain it.

It joins the search terms with `"), p:contains("`. Then it just adds the missing `p:contains("` and `")` to the ends of the result string and searches for it.

Comment: Thanks man. This actually works perfectly. I wouldn't have thought of that in a million years.

Comment: Note that this will likely fail if user enters quotes `"` into search string. // EDIT: I thought quotes could be escaped, but seems that escaping does not help. `("` breaks this selector even with backslashes added.

Comment: Breaks for me only when I use   ")

Answer (score 1):

A combination of `$.filter` and $.each (or array.forEach, if you don't care about ie8) can also be of use here:

```
var searchTerms = ["how", "test"];

$('div').filter(function () {
    $text = $(this).text();
    var found = 0;
    $.each(searchTerms, function (index, term) {
        found = $text.indexOf(term) > -1 ? found +1 : found;
    })
    return found;
}).addClass('match');
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BhtaJ/1/)**